# Why SeleniumIDE For Each loop uses one letter as local variable instead of whole word

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I've tried SeleniumIde for first time few days ago and everyday been struggling a lot to just understand basic workflow however now I managed to login to webpage and store variable.

That variable, i wanted then to use as list.

The variable looks like this:
item1,item2,item3,item4

However, when use for each loop on this variable, it doesnt go item1>item2>item3, it goes i>t>e>m>1>i>t>e>m>2 etc. Either Selenium doesn't automatically parse it (make array from variable) as array, or im doing something wrong.

I'm sorry I have no clue how to import code from SeleniumIDE, therefore ill show screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO5sJ.png

You can see on screen that I store variable, make foreach loop of it, and the loop writes one letter instead of one word in certain field on webpage.

Any help appreciated